# Struts Action without session (Liferay)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I would like to create a simple struts action within Liferay, which would be a publicly accessible path to get some data. This is all perfectly fine, and I am able to create as many of those as I need. However, the data comes with several extra http headers that are not needed, and more importantly, with a cookie and a session.

What I would like to do is to simply get the client to obtain its data and go, no sessions are required. Is that a way to achieve this? I know we can disable sessions for the entire system, but I would like to be punctual.

The code is pretty standard:

```
@Component( immediate = true, property = {
        "path=" + AuthPublicPath.ASSET_BRIDGE_URL, "service.ranking:Integer=" + Integer.MAX_VALUE
}, service = StrutsAction.class )
```

Comment: struts action as in "portlet action" or in "servlet action"? Which version? And can you show code that you already have but are unhappy with? You know that you can just ignore the session, right? Any reason why you don't, when you don't need it?

Comment: I added the code, but it is just a regular OSGi module. nothing special. The version, it has being there since GA3, it is now on LR GA5.

Comment: about ignoring, that is not my goal here, I know I could, but...

Comment: The question is why would you use struts action in the first place? I think the JAX-RS capabilities of Liferay 7 are a better way to go now.

Comment: That is one comment that is in my head. The resulting Struts based module came from migration, 6. For private parts struts was also handy, and session tracking was desirable. but reality changed. I am thinking about a redesign now, or just include a simple OSGi servlet for the entry-point that does not require auth. JAX-RS capabilities of Liferay 7 are also easy now. But before doing that, I was interested on knowing if I could use this old code instead, keeping change to the minimum.

Comment: Ps: jax-rs causes the same issue.